# Good idea to add Google MX records with old records to not lose mail?

Tags: mx-record

Currently im looking to transition to google apps for mail service. Right now I'm using my own mail server. Would it be wise to just leave my current MX entries as is and just add in the google MX entries with a higher priority? Since propagation can take 24-72 hours, it can at least fallback onto my old mail server MX entries?

And once its fully propagated I delete the old MX entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do this if your old mail server is still capable of receiving your mail.

Systems that have cached your old MX setting will use this until it's expired and everyone else will use the new one.

If at all, doing this might even delay the complete transition to the new service.

Comment: so ur saying just delete the old MX entries completely.  and just put in the new google MX ones then? im just worried it might lose mail but since the old mail server will still be up.. i can still get it then. just that i have to check in both places?

Answer (score -1):

Google Apps are ready to receive mail for your domain even before you set the MX records. This is not written in the documentatuon, but is known fact.

When you change the MX recirds to Google's, there will be period of propagation of cource. During this perion, some emails will go to gGoogle Apps, some will go to your old mail server.

You can ask your users to check both Google Apps and old mail servers for a week,

or you can download the mails from your old POP3 to Google Apps. In this second scenario, assuming you have all the mails on old server, you can migrate all the mail to Google Apps as well.

Only "disadvantage" to this second download is you need to use "fake" email identification during the download - e.g. use something like user@domain.old.com instead the real domain. When you try to set it up you will see what I mean.

Another disadvantage will be you need to do this as per user basis. If you have 4-5 users will be fast, but you might have 100 users or even more.

Finally during this download you can set up rules so the old emails will go to respective folders etc.

Hope this adds new useful info to existing posted answer.

Comment: what is wrong with -1 ? I am using at least 40 google apps domains for more than 10 years now and I can guarantee what I stated is true. gmail part of the google apps, works from the moment google aps account is created. so called activation is more or less instructions on the screen how to set mx records.